Problema al montar /system en Android con mknod en C
Holaque tal :D, he estado trabajando de fondo con android y su kernel, para ser especifico con un lg e510f del cual ya obtuve el codigo fuente del kernel, y una custom rom modificada para este, ahora mi objetivo es simular un switch_root (para poder pasarle el control al directorio en /system) pero en c ya que el init que viene en el ramdisk del boot.img parece que no soporta este comando, y al intentar ejecutarlo con busybox no funciona ya que el init ejecutar el busybox con un pid distinto al 1 que es nesesario para ejeuctar el init.rc.
Bueno eso ha sido una mini introducción rapida ahora el problema en si, despues de haber montado correctamente las particiones de proc, sysfs y dev procedi a montar la particion de /dev/block/mtdblock1 en la carpeta /system, sin emabrgo para esto resulta que nesesito crear el /dev/block/mtdblock1 en si :O, despues de investigar un rato muuuuy largo llegue al siguiente fragmento de codigo:
if (mknod("/dev/block/mtdblock9", S_IFBLK | 0660, makedev(31, 9)) != 0) {
    return error_exit("Error creando el nodo lol UwU\n");
}
else {
    /*sleep(40);*/
}

El cual crea el nodo que seria el /dev/block/mtdblock1 (se crea correctamente ya que si entra en el sleep asi que lo comente) el cual uso de la siguiente forma:
if (mkdir("/system", 0755)!=0){ // Crea el directorio si no existe con permisos adecuados
    return error_exit("Error al crear el directorio /data\n");
}
else {
    sleep(20);
}

if(mount("/dev/block/mtdblock9", "/system", "yaffs2", MS_RELATIME, "rw")!=0){
    return error_exit("No se puede montar /system\n");
}
else {
    sleep(20);
}

Peor esto siempre falla y no se monta la particion en /system, no se a que se deba ya he intentado muchas cosas pero no funcionan.
A continucación doy informacion extra que fue tomada desde la rom de android customizada sin ser modificada por mi
localhost / # df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   214256        32    214224   0% /dev
tmpfs                   214256         0    214256   0% /mnt/asec
tmpfs                   214256         0    214256   0% /mnt/obb
/dev/block/mtdblock1    230400    127764    102636  55% /system
/dev/block/mtdblock9    168448     11056    157392   7% /data
/dev/block/mtdblock8     65536     30080     35456  46% /cache
/dev/block/mtdblock9    168448     11056    157392   7% /cache/download
localhost / # mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
none on /acct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
tmpfs on /mnt/asec type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
tmpfs on /mnt/obb type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
none on /dev/cpuctl type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu)
/dev/block/mtdblock1 on /system type yaffs2 (ro,relatime)
/dev/block/mtdblock9 on /data type yaffs2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
/dev/block/mtdblock8 on /cache type yaffs2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
/dev/block/mtdblock9 on /cache/download type yaffs2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)

Tambien comparto el codigo completo de lo que llevo hasta ahora:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/reboot.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>  // Para mknod()
#include <sys/types.h> // Para tipos de dispositivos como S_IFBLK
#include <sys/sysmacros.h>

// Funcion para imprimir los errores, sin embargo aun no sirve de nada :>
int error_exit(char *error){
    perror(error);
    return -1;
}

// Nota: Cada /*sleep(20);*/ es usado para comprobar si funciona el codigo como se espera,
// si mi celular no se reinicia antes de esos 20 segs que mido manualmente significa que 
// el codigo funciona, debido a que no he podido montar ni una sola particion de las que 
// deseo no he podido arreglar eso y este es el unico metodo de comprobar si funciona el bloque  
// de codigo deseado que tengo disponible hasta ahora

int main() {

    // Se monta /proc con proc
    if (mount("proc", "/proc", "proc", MS_NOSUID | MS_NOEXEC | MS_NODEV, "") != 0) {
        // Si falla, imprime el error y sale
        return error_exit("Error montando /proc\n");
    }
    else {
        /*sleep(20);*/
    }

    // Se monta /sys con sysfs
    if (mount("sysfs", "/sys", "sysfs", MS_RELATIME, NULL) != 0) {
        // Si falla, imprime el error
        return error_exit("Error montando /sys\n");
    }
    else {
        //error
        /*sleep(20);*/
    }

    mkdir("/dev", 0755); // Se crea /dev con permisos suficientes

    // Intenta montar /dev usando devtmpfs
if (mount("tmpfs", "/dev", "tmpfs", MS_RELATIME, "mode=755") != 0) {
        // Si falla, imprime el error
        return error_exit("Error montando /dev\n");
    }
    else {
        /*sleep(20);*/
    }

    mkdir("/dev/block", 0755); // Se crea /dev/block con permisos suficientes

    // Se comprueba la existencia de /dev/block/
    if (access("/dev/block", F_OK)!=0){
        return error_exit("Error, no existe el directorio /dev/block/mtdblock1\n");
    }
    else {
        /*sleep(20);*/
    }

    // Se crea el nodo de /dev/mtdblock9 para montar /system
    if (mknod("/dev/mtdblock9", S_IFBLK | 0660, makedev(31, 9)) != 0) {
        return error_exit("Error creando el nodo lol UwU\n");
    }
    else {
        /*sleep(40);*/
    }

    // Se comprueba la existencia de /dev/mtdblock9 una vez mas
    if (access("/dev/mtdblock9", F_OK)!=0){
        return error_exit("Error, no existe el directorio /dev/block/mtdblock1\n");
    }
    else {
        /*sleep(20);*/
    }

    // Se crea el directorio /system con permisos suficientes
    if (mkdir("/system", 0755)!=0){ // Crea el directorio si no existe con permisos adecuados
        return error_exit("Error al crear el directorio /data\n");
    }
    else {
        sleep(20);
    }

    // Se intenta montar /dev/block/mtdblock9 como /system
    if(mount("/dev/block/mtdblock9", "/system", "yaffs2", MS_RELATIME, "rw")!=0){
        return error_exit("No se puede montar /system\n");
    }
    else {
        sleep(20);
    }

    // A partir de aqui no pasa por lo que lo de abajo no sirve correctamente asi que se puede ignorar y por eso no esta debidamente documentado, ignorar

    if (mkdir("/data", 0755)!=0){ // Crea el directorio si no existe con permisos adecuados
        return error_exit("Error al crear el directorio /data\n");
    }

    if(mount("/dev/block/mtdblock9", "/data", "yaffs2", MS_RELATIME | MS_NOATIME, "rw")!=0){
        return error_exit("No se puede montar /data\n");
    }
    else {
        if (access("ashgdasgyukgu/data/busyboxdesde", F_OK)!=0){
            return error_exit("Error, no existe el directorio /dev/block/mtdblock1\n");
        }

        sleep(2);

        // Abrir el archivo con los permisos de creación
        FILE *fd = fopen("/system/from_main2", "w");
        if (fd==NULL)error_exit("Error!\n");
        else{

        // Escribir algo en el archivo (opcional)
        char *text = "Este es un archivo de prueba\n";
        fprintf(fd, "Este es un archivo de prueba\n");

        // Cerrar el archivo
        sync();
        fclose(fd);

        // Sincronizar los discos y asegurar que todo está guardado antes de reiniciar
        sync();

        sleep(20);
    }
}

/*if (mkdir("/dev/block", S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH)!=0) {*/
/*    error_exit("Error creando el /dev/block\n");*/
/*}*/
/*else {*/
/*    sleep(20);*/
/*}*/

return 0;
}

La version de compiladodor cruzado que estoy usando:
❯ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

La version del toolchain que es la unica con la que de forma exitosa he podido compilar el kernel sin problemas:
❯ ../../tools/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc --version
arm-eabi-gcc (GCC) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

La version del kernel extraida del Makefile:
VERSION = 2
PATCHLEVEL = 6
SUBLEVEL = 35
EXTRAVERSION = .13
NAME = Yokohama

Cualquier otra informacion que sea requerida con gusto la proporcionare, muchas gracias de antemano :D

Hola Jose. Bienvenido. En principio el dispositivo debería ser creado por el driver cuando es cargado por el kernel, al menos en los sistemas modernos. No recuerdo si para un kernel 2.6 (que parece que es lo que estás usando) es también el caso. Has incluido el soporte para Flash en el kernel que has compilado?. Otra cosa, switch_root es un programa. Si no lo incluyes en tu disco RAM no está. Para implementarlo normalmente usas chroot, pero init lo que suele hacer es una llamada a pivot_root que es también una llamada al sistema. Comprueba el manual. Son cosas bastante distintas

Hola que tal, gracias por tu respuesta, el kernel lo compile con el soporte que mencionas mas aparte otras opciones relacionadas con las memorias NAND de mi lg, realmente mi intencion era emular el swirch_root, es decir, escribir el mio pero ahora que lo veo parece ser que no es nesesario, investigue un poco mas sobre pivot_root y parece ser que esta es un interrrupcion del sistema la cual cambia la raiz a una carpeta new_dir mientras mueve el actual root a una subcarpeta dentro de esta, sin embargo parece que sigo teniendo el mismo problema de la pregunta de montar la particion mtdblock1

El soporte para flash lo incluiste en el kernel o como módulo?. Durante el arranque el kernel debería encontrar todas las particiones (suponiendo que existan) Si hay algún problema deberías poder verlo en los logs de arranque .¿Podrías compartir los mensajes que se muestran durante el boot?. Ten en cuenta que, además del soporte para Flash necesitas los sistemas de ficheros (en tu caso yasff2) en el kernel. Supongo que también lo has incluido, pero por si acaso.

Okay mira, el soporte para flash lo he definido en el Makefile del kernel: CONFIG_MTD_MSM_NAND=y y el kernel funciona bien dentro de la custom rom que consegui, reemplaze su kernel con el mio que compile, y con respecto a los logs, no he encontrado una forma de conseguirlos, debido al init que mostre, es muy basico y no tiene capacidades de escribir los logs en alguna particion, ademas desconosco en que el kernel va guardando los logs de manera persistente, de hecho cuando logre montar correctamente las particiones lo primero que hare sera integrar los logs del sistema para mejorar las pruebas

Hola Jose, Si no puedes volcar logs en la pantalla o el disco y no tienes acceso a un puerto serie/consola, yo intentaría utilizar la red. Crea un socket en tu programa y vuelca el contenido de /proc/kmsg en él para leerlos en otra máquina. Sin saber que está pasando es difícil decir cual puede ser el problema.

Hola de nuevo, ya logre dibujar en la pantalla, estoy usando una biblioteca que yo mismo escribi paradibujar sobre el frmaebuffer, he creado su respectivo nodo en /dev/graphics/fb0 y huala, ha funcionado, ahora estare ocupado logrando hacer que se impriman los logs del kernel de forma optima, pronto volvere con los logs completos del kernel

Estupendo!. Solamente tienes que poder visualizarlos para ver si se está produciendo algún error durante el arranque. Puede ser algún detalle tonto que estemos pasando por alto, pero que se haga obvio al ver el log.
